# What are most common concepts that Allah tell us in Quran?

Tags: quran

Salam,

I had a currious question from a non-muslim friend, and I do not have enough knowledge to answer..

The question was : When we read and understand Quran (fully), what are the most common concepts, messages, or in another words, if to make percentage of most important things in Quran, what would be those things ?

Exemaple : 30% of Quran is focused in "what is allowed to eat/drink", 10% is relationship with parents, 20% rules to follow for mariage..

I really hope that my question will not be misunderstood and will not offence anyone.

Comment: Your question is kinda hard to answer, lol. Tell your friend that the main concepts are : worship Allah alone, how and why people will go to hell/heaven, how is Hell and how is Heaven, the day of judgement (how it will happen), important stories of Prophets (Yusuf for example), some lessons, what is halal and what is haram, some instructions for the people at the time, etc... It would be too hard to get percentages but tell your friend that.

Comment: The Holy Quran is full of many different lessons and commands which are there to invoke man kind to reflect upon his existence and teach his wisdom. Though "Tawheed" is probably the core of the Quran; to worship The Lord Of The Worlds Allah *ALONE*, without any partners as there is nothing like Him Subhanahu Wa Ta'la. Advise your friend to read the Quran and discover the miracles within it.

Comment: The qur'an is a guidline for all life matters and between these there are several relationships. Therefore I strongly suggest you to give your question a certain focus.